# Find $f(x)$ if $f(x)f\left (\frac{xf(x)+4}{x}\right)=1$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Find $f(x)$ if $$f(x)f\left(\frac{xf(x)+4}{x}\right )=1$$
>   $f:\mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$ is an increasing function and $xf(x)+2>0$

The term in the right bracket is complicating the problem. I can't figure out how to get rid of it or use it properly. The only feasible thing that I can figure out is to assume a function to be a polynomial and then brute force my way which is a bad way to do math.

Comment: Since $f$ is increasing, it is also invertible. Have you tried finding $f^{-1}(x)$ instead?

Comment: Perhaps starting with a limit might help: $\lim_{x\to\infty}[f(f(x)+\frac 4x)-\frac 1{f(x)}]=0$.  In the other direction, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}[f(f(x)+\frac 4x)-\frac 1{f(x)}]=0$.  Roughly, this gives that $f(x)$ and $\frac 1{f(x)}$ are very nearly the same value at each of these extremes.  This seems to be in contradiction with the condition that $f$ is increasing...

Comment: A bit more thinking about the limit approach leads me to consider the function $f(x)=a-\frac bx$, which is quite interesting considering the specific later conditions on $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f:\Bbb R^+\mapsto \Bbb R$ we have $xf(x)+2\gt 0\to f(x)\gt-\frac 2x$.  This together with $f$ increasing suggests that a good function to consider is $f(x)=a-\frac bx$.  Plugging into the functional equation,

$$\left(a-\frac bx\right)\left(a-\frac b{a-\frac bx+\frac 4x}\right)=1\\
(ax-b)\left(a-\frac{bx}{ax-b+4}\right)=x\\
(ax-b)(a^2x-ab+4a-bx)=ax^2-bx+4x\\
(a^3-ab)x^2-2a^2bx+4a^2x+ab^2-4ab+b^2x=ax^2-bx+4x$$

From this, if $a$ is non-zero there is no solution aside from the trivial $a=1, b=0$, so letting $a=0$ gives $b^2+b=4$, which resolves as $b=-\frac 12\pm\frac{\sqrt {17}}2$.  Either branch satisfies $xf(x)+2\gt 0$, giving solutions $f(x)=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{17}}{2x}$. Of these, only the negative branch is increasing and thus meets all the conditions on $f$.